# Cannot get determinant of matrix

Tags: warning-messages, variable-definitions

I have the following variables

```
Σ = {{64, 40.8, 80}, {40.8, 289, 238}, {80, 238, 400}};
μ = {{9}, {12}, {15}};
ι = {{1}, {1}, {1}};
```

And then I define the following matrix:

```
A = {{Transpose[μ].Inverse[Σ].μ, 
Transpose[μ].Inverse[Σ].ι}, {Transpose[μ].Inverse[Σ].ι, 
Transpose[ι].Inverse[Σ].ι}};
```

Which gives me the matrix:

[image]

Now when I try to get the determinant of the matrix i get an error:
[image]

Any1 know what the problem is?

Comment: `Det` will take the determinant  of a symbolic matrix, so you could also use something like `Det[A] /. {\[CapitalSigma] -> {{64, 40.8, 80}, {40.8, 289, 238}, {80, 
     238, 400}}, \[Mu] -> {9, 12, 15}, \[Iota] -> {1, 1, 1}}` with A as defined below by Bob Hanlon (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148259/106)

Answer (score 11):

Mathematica does not distinguish between row and column vectors ([`"The Wolfram Language represents vectors as lists, and never needs to distinguish between row and column cases."`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/OperationsOnVectors.html)). Consequently, change your definitions of `μ`, `ι`, and `A`.

```
Σ = {{64, 40.8, 80}, {40.8, 289, 238}, {80, 238, 400}};
μ = {9, 12, 15};
ι = {1, 1, 1};

(A = {{μ.Inverse[Σ].μ, μ.Inverse[Σ].ι}, 
  {μ.Inverse[Σ].ι, ι.Inverse[Σ].ι}}) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Det[A]

0.0021282
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the structure of `A`. You need to use `Flatten` and `First` to get rid of the curly around each number.

```
Σ = {{64, 40.8, 80}, {40.8, 289, 238}, {80, 238, 400}};
μ = {{9}, {12}, {15}};
ι = {{1}, {1}, {1}};

A = {{First@Flatten[Transpose[μ].Inverse[Σ].μ], 
   First@Flatten[Transpose[μ].Inverse[Σ].ι]}, {First@
    Flatten[Transpose[μ].Inverse[Σ].ι], 
   First@Flatten[Transpose[ι].Inverse[Σ].ι]}};

A // TraditionalForm
```

> [image: Blockquote]

```
Det[A]
```

> 0.0021282

Answer (score 4):

What you have constructed is a four-dimensional array (matrix of matrices).

To contruct a normal two-dimensional matrix from two-dimensional blocks use `ArrayFlatten`:

```
A = ArrayFlatten[{{Transpose[μ].Inverse[Σ].μ, Transpose[μ].Inverse[Σ].ι}, 
                  {Transpose[μ].Inverse[Σ].ι, Transpose[ι].Inverse[Σ].ι}}];
```

> ```
> {{1.41771,  0.151394 }, 
>  {0.151394, 0.0176682}}
> ```